# C++ socket client/server server do not response to client

Tags: c++, sockets

I am beginner in socket programming and I have problem with my client/server program, client  can't connect to server. I have no idea why, please help. I want to fined out where is the problem.

Server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   WSAData WinSockData;
   WORD Version = MAKEWORD(2,1);
   long SUCESSFUL;

   SUCESSFUL = WSAStartup(Version,&WinSockData);

    SOCKADDR_IN ADDRESS;
    int AdresSize = sizeof(ADDRESS);

   SOCKET sock_LISTEN;
   SOCKET sock_CONNECT;

   sock_CONNECT = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);
   ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
   ADDRESS.sin_family = AF_INET;
   ADDRESS.sin_port = htons(27015);

    sock_LISTEN = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);
    bind(sock_LISTEN,(SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS,sizeof(ADDRESS));

   for(;;)
   {
       listen(sock_LISTEN,SOMAXCONN);
        cout << "Waiting for connections..." << endl;

       if(sock_CONNECT = accept(sock_LISTEN,(SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS,&AdresSize))
       {

        cout << "Conection was found" << endl;

        SUCESSFUL = send(sock_CONNECT,"Hello",5,NULL);
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   WSAData WinSockData;
   WORD DLLVersion;
   DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
   long SUCESSFUL;
   SUCESSFUL = WSAStartup(DLLVersion,&WinSockData);

   string RESPONSE;
   string CONVERTER;
   char MESSAGE[200];

   SOCKADDR_IN ADDRESS;

   SOCKET sock;
   sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);

   ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
   ADDRESS.sin_family = AF_INET;
   ADDRESS.sin_port = htonl(27015);

   cout << "Do You want to connect to this server (Y/N)" << endl;
   cin >> RESPONSE;

   RESPONSE[0] = tolower(RESPONSE[0]);

   if(RESPONSE == "n")
   {
       cout << "Quiting" <<endl;

   }else if (RESPONSE == "y")
   {
        connect(sock,(SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS,sizeof(ADDRESS));

        SUCESSFUL = recv(sock,MESSAGE,sizeof(MESSAGE),NULL);

        CONVERTER = MESSAGE;

       cout << CONVERTER << endl;
   }else
   {
       cout << "Illegal response" <<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the client or the server not working? (Your title said one thing, and the question another)

Comment: Where are the error messages, exceptions, outputs and all the other stuff you found out during your own debugging efforts?  Check returns from all system calls for errors and, if found, get the errno or GetLastError returns and print them out.  Also, on server, you only need to call listen() once - move it outside the loop.  Also, what ravenspoint says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks odd

```
ADDRESS.sin_port = htons(27015);
```

and this looks even odder

```
ADDRESS.sin_port = htonl(27015);
```

Use htons for both.

If that doesn't work,  just write

```
ADDRESS.sin_port = 27015;
```

Comment: Or maybe just using `getaddrinfo`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for incorrect question. I just missed  "htol".